# Is a visa required for travel to Iceland if I have the EU Blue Card?

Tags: germany, indian-citizens, iceland

I have a blue card from Germany but I am a non-EU citizen (India, to be precise). I'm planning to travel to Iceland in the summer for a few days. Will I need a visa to be able to enter Germany? If yes, how do I apply for it?

Comment: I guess you want to know whether you want to know whether you need a visa for Iceland.

Comment: Is your flight directly from Germany to Iceland (intra-Schengen), or are you flying via the UK (outside Schengen)? That probably matters.

Comment: @GregHewgill Yes, flight is direct from Germany to Iceland.

Comment: @Willeke More precisely, I wanted to be reassured of the fact that the answers given here would be sufficient to proceed with my travel plans without having to contact Iceland's consulate for the same information. I guess I should go ahead and book my tickets :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No**, you don't need a visa for Iceland, if your whole trip remains within the Schengen area.

Quoting the official EU Blue Card Network [website](http://www.apply.eu/BlueCard/), you're entitled to:

> Free movement within the Schengen area

However, like @Greg Hewgill mentioned, if you're transiting through the UK or Northern Ireland, you might need a transit visa because they're not part of Schengen

Comment: Indians won't need a visa for airside transit

Comment: And the Blue Card (or other uniform format residence permits from EU countries) also exempts their holders from the DATV requirement. (+1)

Comment: @Calchas in the UK ?

Comment: @Blackbird57 Yes, sorry, in the UK.